# Adding Key Phrase Extraction to Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have successfully integrated Azure Cognitive Search and that is generally working as expected.  Now, I'm being asked to integrate the Key Phrase Extraction Skillset.

We have created the All-in-one key, updated the index to include Language Detection and Key Phrase Extraction (Key Phrase requires a language code on the document), and that index update was successful... or so we believe.   When looking at the Azure Console I see all the skillsets defined, the properties exist on the document, but there is no data in those fields.

My example document looks like this

```cs
public class SearchableDocument {
    [SimpleField(IsKey = true, IsFilterable = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [SearchableField(IsFilterable = true)]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [SimpleField]
    public string[] KeyPhrases { get; set; }

    [SimpleField]
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then the index setup looks like this

```cs
public void CreateOrUpdateSkillsetAsync()
{
    var serviceEndpoint = CreateServiceEndPoint();
    var credential = new AzureKeyCredential(_cognitiveApiKey);

    var languageDetectSkill = CreateLanguageDetectionSkill();
    var keyPhraseSkill = CreateKeyPhraseExtractionSkill();

    var skills = new List<SearchIndexerSkill>
    {
        languageDetectSkill,
        keyPhraseSkill
    };

    var skillSetName = _cognitiveIndexName;
    var skillSet = new SearchIndexerSkillset(skillSetName, skills);
    skillSet.Description = _configProvider.GetCurrentEnvironmentName();
    skillSet.CognitiveServicesAccount = new CognitiveServicesAccountKey(_cognitiveServiceAllInOneKey);
    
    var client = new SearchIndexerClient(serviceEndpoint, credential);
    client.CreateOrUpdateSkillset(skillSet);
}

private LanguageDetectionSkill CreateLanguageDetectionSkill()
{
    var inputMappings = new List<InputFieldMappingEntry>();

    inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry("text")
    {
        Source = "/document/Text",
    });

    var outputMappings = new List<OutputFieldMappingEntry>
    {
        new OutputFieldMappingEntry("languageCode")
        {
            TargetName = "LanguageCode"
        }
    };

    var skill = new LanguageDetectionSkill(inputMappings, outputMappings)
    {
        Name = "Language Detection",
        Description = "Detect language",
        Context = "/document/*",
    };

    return skill;
}

private KeyPhraseExtractionSkill CreateKeyPhraseExtractionSkill()
{
    var inputMappings = new List<InputFieldMappingEntry>();

    inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry("text")
    {
        Source = "/document/Text",
        
    });
    inputMappings.Add(new InputFieldMappingEntry("languageCode")
    {
        Source = "/document/LanguageCode"
    });

    var outputMappings = new List<OutputFieldMappingEntry>
    {
        new OutputFieldMappingEntry("keyPhrases")
        {
            TargetName = "KeyPhrases"
        }
    };

    var keyPhraseExtractionSkill = new KeyPhraseExtractionSkill(inputMappings, outputMappings)
    {
        Name = "KeyPhrase Extraction",
        Description = "Extract the key phrases",
        Context = "/document/*",
        DefaultLanguageCode = KeyPhraseExtractionSkillLanguage.En,
    };

    return keyPhraseExtractionSkill;
}
```

After updating the index with the skillsets, I was expecting that the properties `LangaugeCode` and `KeyPhrases` would start to fill in. But that is not happing for new documents or existing.

Answer (score 1):

The [skillset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-working-with-skillsets) needs to be attached to an indexer in order to run which then reads from a data source, performs enrichments and writes to the index. If you check your indexer execution history there should be a few warnings that can offer some hints.

1. Skill input should refer to the property name of the data source, not index. Depending where your data comes from it would require different "names" to refer the input text. If your data source type is a storage account with default parsing then the input probably should be `/document/content` instead of `/document/Text`; or if it's Cosmos DB then it would be `/document/<property name>`; or see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#index-content-and-metadata) if the text comes from the blob metadata.
2. The skill context should be `/document` since each document is a "bag of properties" instead of an array.
3. The indexer with the skillset needs [output field mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-output-field-mapping) to describe which index field to populate. So from your index definition, it would be

```
"outputFieldMappings": [
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "/document/LanguageCode",
            "targetFieldName": "LanguageCode"
        },
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "/document/KeyPhrases",
            "targetFieldName": "KeyPhrases"
        }
]
```

4. Every time there's a change to the index or skillset definition the indexer needs to be [reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/reset-indexer) and then [run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/run-indexer) again to pick up changes. Alternatively, consider using a [cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-incremental-index) to avoid rerunning skills that didn't change.

Comment: I am programmatically adding documents to the search index via the C# api (I have to do a lot of data scrubbing, so I cannot point directly at my database and go).  So in theory, my source is the Azure Search index.

Comment: Unfortunately skillsets can't be used if you're pushing documents to the index directly. Is it possible to do the scrubbing with a view? That would probably be the ideal setup so sensitive data never leave the database and you can set the indexer on a schedule to fetch data in the background without calling the index API directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers

Comment: Got it.  Thank you.